# Application Insights - How to correlate a operation that span multiple services?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a operation that starts in a micro service and span several others. All the services are monitored by applications insights but report to different instances.

I was wondering: is there a out-of-the-box way to track the operation across all these services? and if so, how can I use it (or set it up)?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/app-insights-microservices/

Comment: Do you use AI SDKs in your microservices? If yes then everything should work out of a box (for data in different Application Insights resources as well). Do you see different picture?

Comment: This should work out of the box. Click on any one of the requests received by any one of the microservices. That should open up a End to End tracing view which will give you a view of what you are looking for